# what's the best storage for text

Tags: storage

I have an application that just only use for show information and search data. and my datatype is text and has larg size. would you please tell me what's the best storage for it. also I don't want to use SQL database.
thaks

Comment: Can you tell use more details about your application? How big is the data set size? Is the data one big file or many smaller ones? Why not use a database engine?

Comment: 4 to 1 that you don't want to use an SQL database because you don't know SQL, or because your host doesn't have it. FYI, those are wrong "reasons".

Answer (score 0):

I would just store it to disk with a plain file name. What language are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Bryan Ross, but I would go further and say store in in text but using xml protocol. This way data is better structured and opens up lots of options if you even need the data imported.

http://xmlfiles.com/xml/xml_usedfor.asp